# Cloud9 Hosting specs

Tags: cloud9-ide

I'm reading [this Rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book), which suggests using [Cloud9](https://c9.io) for the IDE. It also recommends Heroku for hosting your app.

It turns out that Cloud9 has built-in hosting *of some sort*; every Cloud9 app also has a public URL, and you can run Rails yourself (albeit with Webrick by default).

As much as I Google, I can't find any details about the hosting offering Cloud9 provides. Webrick aside, what are the limits on RAM, etc.? I know Cloud9 uses Docker and Ubuntu to build a VM, but I can't find much more than that.

(As much as I am following the recommendation to use Heroku for hosting, I can't help but wonder how the two compare.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclosure: I work for Cloud9 :) http://c9.io/site/about

Cloud9 is meant for development, so it's hosting is like running rails on your laptop and pointing your domain at it (albeit with a fair bit more bandwidth). It's ok for showing your project to some friends or testers, but not for running a proper website. You'd also have to make your project public which means other will be able to see your source code.

Also on free accounts your project is archived after a week of no development so it won't be accessible from the outside world any more. It is unarchived when you work on it again.

Only premium accounts workspaces are kept running, because we can't afford to keep free users workspaces taking up ram / disk when they're not being actively used. Free users get 512MB ram + 1.5GB disk and premium users get 1GB ram + 5GB disk per project.

Comment: I work for Cloud9 https://c9.io/site/about :) I don't think there are any docs about this, I'll create a page on that soon.

Comment: Only premium accounts workspaces are kept running, because we can't afford to keep free users workspaces taking up ram / disk when they're not being actively used. Free users get 512MB ram + 1.5GB disk and premium users get 1GB ram + 5GB disk per project.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly; 512MB of RAM allocated to non-premium users; 1GB for premium users. There is enough for a developer to work with.

Also, unless you're willing to share your source code with your visitors — there is no way to have it as a hosting platform.

Private Workspace = Private to developers/workspace users.

Public Workspace  = Public to all; even the source code.

https://c9.io/site/blog/2013/05/can-i-use-cloud9-to-do-x/

Comment: It's 512MB per project for free users and 1GB per project for premium users.

Comment: Can you point me to any page on their site or any other proof that it's 128MB RAM for their hosted platform?

Comment: @ashes999 I've put a source; although Tim has already beat me to the facts. ;)

Comment: @user3650841 it's hard to beat employees for facts :) +1 for effort though, thanks.